# How to delete the new array in c++?

Tags: c++

I have created a new point function in c++, where I create a new array by Dynamic memory allocation. However, when I want to delete the array in main function, it reports errors like:

```
'Assessment_1.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'
'Assessment_1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. 
The thread 0x22dc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
HEAP[Assessment_1.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00050000, 0005F25C )
Assessment_1.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

The return_array.cpp contains the function in which user inputs the keyboards.

```
#include<iostream>

#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
//const static int length = 3;

int* input() {

    //static int number[length];  fixed length for input 

    static int* number_array;
    int number_length = 30;
    int index = 0;
    number_array = new int[number_length];
    cout << "enter (ESC) to escape the program!" << endl;

    while (_getch() != 27)
    {
        cout << "Input your number " << index << " elment: " << endl;
        cin >> number_array[index];
        index = index + 1;
        cout << endl;
    }

    return number_array;
}
```

The practice.cpp contains the main function and the evaluation function of two vectors. The bug is when I add the ***delete []vector_1;***.

```
#include <vector>
#include<iostream>
#include"myFunctions.h"
using namespace std;
const static int length = 3;
bool same_vec(vector<int> a, vector<int> b);

void main() {
    vector<int> new_vector_1(length);
    vector<int> new_vector_2(length);

    int* vector_1 = input();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        new_vector_1[i] = *vector_1;
        cout << *vector_1 << endl;

        vector_1 = vector_1 + 1;
    }
    delete []vector_1;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cout << " The result of vector_1: " << new_vector_1[i] << endl;
    }

    int* vector_2;
    vector_2 = input();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        new_vector_2[i] = *vector_2;
        vector_2 = vector_2 + 1;
    }
    delete []vector_2;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        cout << " The result of vector_2: " << new_vector_2[i] << endl;
    }

    bool qax = same_vec(new_vector_1, new_vector_2);

    if (qax == false) {
        cout << "the items are not match!"<<endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "the items are match!" << endl;
    }

}

bool same_vec(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
    //Evaluate the elements in the two vectors

    bool flag = true;
    int length_a = a.size();
    int length_b = b.size();

    vector<bool> new_bool(length_a);

    for (int i = 0; i < length_a; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length_b; j++) {
            if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                new_bool[i] = true;
                cout << a[i] << " " << b[j] << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < new_bool.size(); i++) {
        if (new_bool[i] == false) {
            flag = false;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}
```

And the myFunction.h is my head file.

```
#pragma once
int* getRandom();

int* input();
```

Can someone helps to solve the problem? I know one solution is delete the line of **delete []vector_1;**. The solution may cause memory-leak.

Comment: You are aware that `vector<int>` exists, why use `int[]` *at all*? `same_vec` is normally spelled `operator ==`, and [already exists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp)

Comment: @Caleth Cause I'm beginner of c++ and I’m not very good at  template. It seems that the template is a great idea to handle the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing the address stored in the `vector_1` pointer, then trying to `delete[]` something that **no longer corresponds** to the pointer returned by the `new` operator in your `input` function.

So, instead of this loop:

```cpp
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        new_vector_1[i] = *vector_1;
        cout << *vector_1 << endl;
        vector_1 = vector_1 + 1; // This line changes the pointer!
    }
    delete []vector_1; // And, here, the pointer is NOT what "new" gave you!
```

Use something like this, instead:

```cpp
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        new_vector_1[i] = vector_1[i]; // You can use the [] operator on the pointer
        cout << *vector_1 << endl;
//      vector_1 = vector_1 + 1; // Remove this line, as it's causing the problem!
    }
    delete []vector_1;
```

Also, you have exactly the same problem in the loop that deals with the `vector_2` pointer - and the same 'fix' will work there, too.

Note: If you don't want to use the `[i]` index operator, but rather use pointer 'arithmetic', then you can change:

```cpp
    new_vector_1[i] = vector_1[i];
```

to:

```cpp
    new_vector_1[i] = *(vector_1 + i);
```

This way, you are adding the value of `i` to the pointer *without* changing that pointer.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I understand the pointer deeper and the pointer ' arithmetic' is so hard for the beginner.